# Does DDD support Perl?

Tags: perl, debugging, ddd-debugger

Can DDD (Data Display Debugger) be used for Perl data structures?

Comment: Perl - programming language, perl - interpreter, but never PERL.

Comment: I guess Stackoverflow is becoming a documentation reading service. Chells apparently never even tried to answer his own question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting the [DDD manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/):

> **What is DDD?**
>
> GNU DDD is a graphical front-end for command-line debuggers such
> as GDB, DBX, WDB, Ladebug, JDB, XDB, the **Perl debugger**, the bash
> debugger bashdb, the GNU Make debugger remake, or the Python
> debugger pydb.